# Drupal Ajax callback null

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal-7

I'm trying to process page data via Jquery and AJAX. I want to send a string to Drupal, append another string, and send it back to the client. I'm getting a "*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'messageLog' of null*" error

This is what I have so far. Thanks for the help:

Drupal module:

```
function exoticlang_chat_log_init(){
drupal_add_js('misc/jquery.form.js');
drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');
}

function exoticlang_chat_log_permission() {
   return array('access ExoticLang Chat Log');
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu().
 */
function exoticlang_chat_logger_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['chatlog'] = array(
        'title'            => t('ChatLog'),
        'type'             => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback'    => 'exoticlang chat log ajax',
        'access_callback' => 'user_access',
        'access arguments' => array('save chat log')
    );
    return $items;
}

function exoticlang_chat_log_ajax($logData){
    $messageLog= 'Drupal has processed this: '.$logData;
    ajax_deliver($messageLog);
    exit;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function sendPrivateMessageLog(privateSessionID, privateChatLog){
    var privateMessageLogJson={'user': myNick, 'chatLog': privateChatLog, 'sessionId': privateSessionID}
    privateMessageLogJson = JSON.stringify(privateMessageLogJson);
    console.log('JSONstringified: ' + privateMessageLogJson);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/chatlog',
        success: exoticlangAjaxCompleted,
        data:'messageLog=' + privateMessageLogJson,
        dataType: 'json'

    });
    return false;
}

function exoticlangAjaxCompleted(data){
    console.log('exoticlangAjaxCompleted!');
    console.log('chat log is: ' + data.messageLog);
    console.log('chat log is: ' + dump(data.messageLog));
    //console.log(dump(data));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `jsonp` as the `dataType`? You should also be able to look at the complete response from the request using firebug.

Comment: Changing it to jsonp didn't help. However, I realized that I was getting a 403 error as the callback. i have done some research on that, and the only thing I can find is not setting the access_aruments on the request side.

Answer (score 0):

@Krister Andersson, your suggestion to use Firebug pointed me in the right direction. I usually don't use it, since it doesn't work very well in Linux.

The javascript was fine, but I had to make a few changes to the PHP:

1) In the chat logger menu, I deleted the access callback line.

2) I added underscores to the items[chatlog] page callback

3) In exoticlang_chat_log_ajax, I used $_POST['messageLog'] instead of passing it in as a function argument

4) instead of using drupal's ajax_deliver, I simply echoed the results.

Final module:

```
<?php

function exoticlang_chat_log_init(){
drupal_add_js('misc/jquery.form.js');
drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');
}

function exoticlang_chat_log_permission() {
  return array(
    'Save chat data' => array(
      'title' => t('Save ExoticLang Chat Data'),
      'description' => t('Send private message on chat close')
    ));
}


/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu().
 */

function exoticlang_chat_logger_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['chatlog'] = array(
        'type'             => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback'    => 'exoticlang_chat_log_ajax',
        'access arguments' => 'Save chat data');
        //'access callback' => 'user_access');
    return $items;
}

function exoticlang_chat_log_ajax(){
    $messageLog=$_POST['messageLog'];
    $chatLog= 'Drupal has processed this: '.$messageLog;
    echo $chatLog;
    drupal_exit();
}
```

I hope this helps someone in the future...

Comment: Although the original question is answered, I have another one - I can't figure out how to get the data from the callback into Javascript. When I try to add an argument to exoticlangAjaxCompleted - ex. exoticlangAjaxCompleted(data), it says that data isn't defined

Comment: I think you will have to send back the data as `json`, try something like `echo json_encode(array('messageLog' => $chatLog));` in your `exoticlang_chat_log_ajax()` function.